# How can I count the total number if rows in a gridview in c#

Tags: c#

I have a gridview with page size 5.
The gridview contain 30 rows. when I export it to excel, it only show 5 rows. How can display all rows in excel sheet from gridview? Not a table because gridview contains rows from rowdatabound event.

```
for (int j = 0; j < gvvessel.Rows.Count; j++)
{
Label lblvess = (Label)gvvessel.Rows[j].FindControl("lblvesselName");
string myVal = lblvess.Text;
Label lblShipEmail = (Label)gvvessel.Rows[j].FindControl("lblShipEmailID");
string mylblShipEmail = lblShipEmail.Text;
Label lblAllowTo = (Label)gvvessel.Rows[j].FindControl("lblAllowToken");
string mylblAllowTo = lblAllowTo.Text;
Label lblAssignToken = (Label)gvvessel.Rows[j].FindControl("lblAssignToken");
string mylAssignToken = lblAssignToken.Text;
Label lblRemainingT = (Label)gvvessel.Rows[j].FindControl("lblRemainingToken");
string mylRemainingT = lblRemainingT.Text;
Label lblpkg = (Label)gvvessel.Rows[j].FindControl("lblpackagedate");
string myVal1 = lblpkg.Text;
Label lbllastupd = (Label)gvvessel.Rows[j].FindControl("lbllastupdate");
string myVal2 = lbllastupd.Text;

}
```

Comment: try to get the data from your source(e.g database)

Comment: Dear sir some data is come with database and some data is come with custom rowdatabound event kindly help me out.so am not try to get the data from your source

Comment: you dont get the point
you need to process again without paging

Comment: paging is mandatory.pls help us sir

Comment: sir you will not get my point i will explain it.i have a gridview which contain 30 rows.it has paging with page size 5. it is export only 5 rows.but i want export 30 rows.

Comment: Currently you are going through all the rows of the GridView, but it only has 5. You should rather get the DataSource of the GridView and loop through that